# Self.frame does not match device dimensions

Tags: swift, layout, xib

I'm trying to get the size of my component in relation to the device, however it ignores the real size and considers the "placeholder" of the xib

it's funny because I have two screens with the same component, in one the xib has the look set like the iPhone 11 in the other the iPhone SE (2s generation), ​​when I run the project, the layout calculation and the value of self.frame is different, even both the screens having the same identical component with the same configuration

> Important I'm not using auto layout inside xib

> It is not possible to use UIScreen in this case as we have other examples where the component is not centered on the screen.

```
private func drawPosition() {
    searchView.addSubview(searchIcon)
    searchView.backgroundColor = .red
    searchIcon.backgroundColor = .yellow
    
    let widht = self.frame.size.width - 12
    widthLeftView = widht / 2
    
    widthConstraint = searchView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: widthLeftView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        searchView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: searchViewSize),
        widthConstraint,
        searchIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: searchIconSize),
        searchIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: searchIconSize),
        searchIcon.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchView.centerYAnchor),
        searchIcon.trailingAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: searchView.trailingAnchor,
            constant: 0)
    ])
    searchBarTextField.leftView = searchView
    searchBarTextField.leftViewMode = .always
}
```

I tried to set the didLayoutSubViews in the controller but nothing changed

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    self.searchBar.setNeedsLayout()
    self.searchBar.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

xib:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You seem to set for only one size class (This size class) . What have you set for (All)

Comment: That's normal I'd say. If you call `drawPosition()` before the didLayout, even if you call inside it setNeedsLayout, it won't calculate again, and the width for the constraint will be the old one. If you recall it, you'll have twice the constraints, and an error.

Comment: @PtitXav I didn't understand your question very well, if it's about the size of the xib components, yes the search bar in specific it doesn't have a defined size it follows the height of an auxiliary view. I can attach more information about it.

Comment: I meant in the third image you can see that the constraint shown are for (This size class). Did you check in (All) class. Class are for different screen sizes and disposition.

Comment: @PtitXav, I just tested it, and there was no change at all

Comment: @Larme then it would be possible to correct it by calling drawPosition() after the VC did Load

Comment: When viewDidLoad is called, you'll have the wrong frame. It loaded (in memory), but didn't render (and adjust) yet.

Comment: @Larme I understand, I tested here both in didLoad and in didAppear and both failed, funny that in didDisappier it worked

Comment: In diddDisappear, didLayout would have been called, that’s why

Comment: But if you want to fix your issue, you want to use half the width - 12. I wouldn't use LayoutAnchors, which doesn't allow this, but I'd use NSLayoutConstraints and visual format.

Comment: @Larme if that's the only way I'll look for it, thanks Larme, it clarified several doubts

Comment: @Larme I had a doubt even using the visual format, the value of the self.frame will still be incorrect, so the visual format corrects what exactly?

Comment: It was late (for me), indeed, VisualFormat might not work either. A solution, would be to keep a reference on the widthConstraint, and in layoutSubview, update its constant (since there, the frame would be the correct one).

Comment: @Larme this worked fine for me, I fixed the problem using the class's override draw(), but it generated problems in other iOS versions and impacted the performance by eating the device's memory little by little, using LayoutSubViews in addition to fixing the problem, I tested and did not have any significant impact on memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I'd to it:

Either add a super view to embed your searchView & searchIcon.
This is a placeholder view, you can set its constraints to half the side of its superview (what you do with `self.frame.width`).
This way, no more "- 12" calculation.
Just let the icon to be at right side, then instead of setting the width of the `searchView`, set its leading to that placeholder, and the trailing to icon.

Another way, would be to keep a reference to the width constraints:

```
var searchViewWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint
```

And override `layoutSubviews()` (if you are in a `UIView`) or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`(if you are in a (UIViewController):

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    searchViewWidthConstraint.constant = self.frame.width - 12
}
```

When `viewDidLoad()` is called, the frame of the different views are the one as seen in InterfaceBuilder. Then, the constraints are applied/calculated (and called again each needed time), and the frame adapts. That's why `self.frame` wasn't correct yet